# Custom view for taking image though camera in ios 7

Tags: iphone, ios7, ios-camera

```
    //---------- viewController.h file has 

    IBOutlet UIView *viewCamera; // custom view for taking camera reason    

    //------------viewController.m :: inside viewDidLoad method
    // -- camera start
            [viewCamera setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

            imgPicker = [UIImagePickerController new];
            imgPicker.allowsEditing = YES;
            imgPicker.delegate = self;    


            imgPicker.cameraOverlayView = viewCamera;


            imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            [self presentViewController:imgPicker animated:NO completion:nil];


// ----- ob btn clicked 
- (IBAction)btnTakePhotoPressed:(id)sender{
    [imgPicker takePicture];
}
```

[image]

App is crashed due to this line, if I comment this line code is running but camera is open in full view, I want to add my camera access on my custom view.

```
imgPicker.cameraOverlayView = viewCamera;
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: cameraOverlay view isa for displaying a view inside of an image picker, is that what you want? From what I can tell, you want to display the image picker inside your own view.

Comment: yes I want to display the image picker inside my own view.